# RPG game damage issues

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make an RPG style game and when I attack the enemy, it will do no damage and the enemy sets my health to -3, can someone help me?

```
@echo off
title RPG BETA
color 0b

set /p player=Welcome to Xero, what's your name?:
cls
echo Hello %player%!
pause
goto start
rem easteregg
if '%player%'=='Niko' goto win
if '%player%'=='nko' goto win

:start
echo In the distant future, the world was on the brink of destrucion.
timeout 3 /nobreak >nul
echo In the midst of the wasteland, a single man, named %player%, will overcome the odds
pause
goto BFight

:BFight
cls
set CPU=20
set CPUN=Scorpion
set gun=1
set gund=10
set playerh=20
:Fight
cls
if '%CPU%'=='0' goto win
if '%playerh%'=='0' goto lose
cls
echo You encounter a %CPUN%!

echo                            %CPUN% Health: %CPU%
echo.
echo                            Your Health: %playerh%

echo [1]Shoot (%gund%) (%gun%)
echo [2]Punch (3 damage)
echo [3]Flee

set /p fp=What do you do?
if 'fp'=='1' goto gun
if 'fp'=='2' goto punch
if 'fp'=='3' goto flee

:gun
if '%gun%'=='0' goto egun
set /a %gun%=-1
echo You fire at the %CPUN%
timeout 4 >nul
echo It hits!
set /a %CPU%=-%gund%
pause
goto cpufight

:egun
echo You have no bullets!
pause
goto Fight

:punch
echo You punch the %CPUN%
timeout 4 >nul
echo It hits!
set /a CPU=-3
pause
goto cpufight

:cpufight
echo The %CPUN% Attacks!
timeout 4
echo It hits!
set /a playerh= -3
pause
goto fight

:win
cls
echo Congradulations, %player%! You win!
pause
```

Note: the game is no quite finished, but if you play it you should be able to see how attacking doesn't work. I also have not programmed the flee option.

Comment: There are several minor syntactical issues with this code. Is this a homework question by any chance?

Comment: I am new to programming and Stack Overflow, so I don't understand what that means, if you are talking literally about like school this is just for fun

Comment: Alright no problem. I've provided some help in an answer below

Comment: Why are you using Batch for that? Batch is very limited and only makes it harder for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several minor issues with this code.  I presume it's a homework question rather than something you have developed yourself?

**Deducting damage values**

There are issues when deducting values to show damage or gun bullets being used. Examples include:

```
set /a %gun%=-1
set /a %CPU%=-%gund%
set /a CPU=-3
```

The variables are named without the percentage symbols, so `%GUN%` should be named `GUN` when using `SET`.  In addition, when performing arithmatic, the code `x =- 1` will NOT subtract one.  It will set `x` to equal `-1`.

The following are corrections of the above:

```
SET /a gun = gun - 1
SET /a CPU = CPU - gund
SET /a CPU = CPU - 3
```

**Collecting input and comparing it**

Another issue is with your 'command' section where you handle the command results in `fp`:

```
if 'fp' == '1' goto gun
if 'fp' == '2' goto punch
if 'fp' == '3' goto flee
```

This basically says if the *text* `fp` equals the *text* `1`.  Obviously that doesn't work.  You need to modify this to use the value of the variable `fp` and the number (remove the `'`):

```
if %fp% == 1 goto gun
if %fp% == 2 goto punch
if %fp% == 3 goto flee
```

**Winning the game**

There is a final issue which is where you calculate the end game when either the player or CPU reaches 0 or lower health.  You currently have:

```
if '%CPU%'=='0' goto win
if '%playerh%'=='0' goto lose
```

This is again comparing the *text* `CPU` or `playerh` to the *textual* value of `0`.  Remove the `'` characters:

```
if %CPU% == 0 goto win
if %playerh% == 0 goto lose
```

However, this will only work if the health reaches 0.  If the health *goes below 0* then it will never happen.  You need to look for 0 or below:

```
if %CPU% LEQ 0 goto win
if %playerh% LEQ 0 goto lose
```

Comment: @agitatedpanda35 You're welcome. Could you mark it as the answer in that case then?

Comment: `set /a CPU=-3` sets `CPU` to `-3`. To decrease by three, use `set /a CPU-=3`

Comment: Yes I already said that in my answer: _the code x =- 1 will NOT subtract one. It will set x to equal -1_. Thanks for the comment